# How to change x-axis from samples/frames to time?

Tags: matplotlib, signal-processing

I need to change the x-axis on this graph from 'samples' to time:
[image]

I created the graph using this process:

```
y, _ = librosa.load('sound/data/kea-song.mp3', 48000)
y /= y.max()

# compute the rmse
e = librosa.feature.rmse(y=y)[0]
e -= e.min()#what does this really do, guessing a kind of normalisation?
e /= e.max()
plt.plot(e)
plt.show()
```

If I don't compute the rmse, this converts the x-axis to time:

```
y, _ = librosa.load('sound/data/kea-song.mp3', 48000)
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y))/48000, y)
```

But after the rmse function I don't know how to do the conversion. I'm guessing it's something to do with the samples in y* being grouped into frames but I can't for the life of me work out how to convert from these frames(if it is frames) to time!

How do I do this? 
Thanks in advance(:

- heres the plot for plt.plot(y):
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested any of this, but by reading the documentation, it seems that the function calculates FFT in frames with the default frame length of 2048 samples and hop length of 512 samples.

That means if have `len(y)` samples in the original audio, you should have `(len(y)-2048)//512` frames on the output. The first frame will be at sample 0, the second frame at sample 512, etc. So you can do this:

```
e_time = np.arange(len(e))*512/48000
plt.plot(e_time, e)
```